# How leave selected checkboxes marked after they are selected and saved in the database

Tags: plugin-development

I created a simple plugin. There is an options page and on it, all existing user roles are displayed. Here is the code:

```
 <h2>Select user roles to send notifications:</h2>
 <?php
   global $wp_roles;
   $roles = $wp_roles->get_names();
   foreach($roles as $role) { $i++; ?>

    <div class="role-wrapper">
    <input name="role[]" type="checkbox" id="user_role-<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $role;?>">
    <label for="user_role-<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $role;?></label>
    </div>

 <?php } ?>
```

After the administrator marks the necessary roles in the checkboxes and clicks the submit button, the selected roles are saved to the database.

```
  if(!empty($_POST['role'])) {
     $new_user_roles = array();
     foreach($_POST['role'] as $key=>$value){
         $new_user_roles[$key] = $value;
     }
     update_option('choosed_users_role', $new_user_roles);
   }
```

Then everything works as it should. But, I don't know how to display the selected checkboxes. After refreshing the page, you cannot see which checkboxes were selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) to retrieve the selected role(s) that were saved in the database, then use [`checked()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/checked/) in your checkboxes. E.g.

```php
// In your code, after this line:
$roles = $wp_roles->get_names();

// Add this which retrieves and stores the selected role(s):
$selected_roles = (array) get_option( 'choosed_users_role' );

/* And then in your <input>, use checked() with in_array():
<input name="role[]" type="checkbox" id="user_role-<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $role;?>"
  <?php checked( in_array( $role, $selected_roles ) ); ?>>
*/
```

### Additional Notes

- If you used the [settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/) to create the options page, you wouldn't need to manually call [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) to save the selected role(s).
- `$i` is never declared in your code, so you should declare it before the `foreach` begins.
- [`WP_Roles::get_names()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_roles/get_names/) returns an associative array with role slug and name pairs, e.g. `'administrator' => 'Administrator'` or `'foo_role' => 'Foo Role'`, so I suggest you to save the role slug and not the name.
- I would use [`wp_roles()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_roles/) like so: `$roles = wp_roles()->get_names()`, which means you don't need to access the global `$wp_roles` variable.